# Partitioning an Existing Table using DBMS_REDEFINITION

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-partitioning

I have a table and I want to partition it, so I start partition it using DBMS_REDEFINITION and I work like this article [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table)

my problem when I start to redefine my table using this code :

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table(
    uname      => USER,        
    orig_table => 'salary',
    int_table  => 'salary_2');
END;
```

I have this problem:

[image]

I abort this redefine using **DBMS_REDEFINITION.abort_redef_table** then  I strat redine using
**DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table** then I get this error:

[image]

However, I drop the snapshot of this table and this error still appears every time I run start_redef_table.

Note:
my table columns are 645.

Comment: Please read the error text `maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000`, check your column number; possible in a temporary table fails adding some helper columns...

Comment: why do you have 1000+ columns? It looks like you have very bad data structure

Comment: thanks marmite, the number of the columns is less than 1000 and it's 645 columns

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu it's an old system and the number of the columns is less than 1000 and it's 645 columns

Comment: There are reports that it's an unpublished bug in Oracle. The patch and fix are provided: https://databaseinternalmechanism.com/2019/01/10/ora-01792-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-table-or-view-is/

Comment: I have oracle 10g

Comment: Is it possible SALARY has a lot of unused columns? That is, columns which have been marked as unused but were never dropped? It's possible that might be the cause of your ORA-01792. Check with `select * from dba_unused_col_tabs where owner = 'ACTRL16' and table_name = 'SALARY'`.

Comment: @APC thank you, I run this query and the result is null. that's table has some null columns, is that's a problem. but my base problem is ora-23539 currently being redefined

Comment: Please don't paste images. Provide error message as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem and now I have a partition table.

I create another table with the same structure as the base table.

Then I insert the data from the old table to the new table.

after that, I delete the old one and rename the new table to the old table name.

but still, redefine doesn't work.